# How to change the style of the header/footer depending on the parity of the page?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr, geometry

## My question

I am trying to have a precise control on the size and on the content of the header and footer of the pages, with different configurations:

- if the page the first page
- on odd pages
- on even pages

What are the best ways to handle this question?

## A picture

Approximately, the document I want to create will look like this

[image]

## What I've tried

So far, I've tried to do

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{bophook}

\begin{document}

\AtBeginPage{%
\strictpagecheck
\ifnum\value{page}>1
    \ifoddpage
      \newgeometry{top=0.5cm, bottom=3cm}
    \else
      \newgeometry{top=3cm, bottom=0.5cm}
    \fi
\else
\fi
}

Test \newpage
Test 2 \newpage
Test 3
\end{document}
```

but as said [there, in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/449954/8323), this approach is doomed to fail.

---

## Post scriptum

In case it can help, here are some pieces of code I use for my document . This is not part of my question, only if it can help!

### Dimensions of the pages and of the footer

I don't really understand the following code but have tested it and it's ok for me. Any comment is welcomed!

```
%%%%%%%%%%
% Layout %
%%%%%%%%%%
\def\myHMargin{2cm}
\def\myVMargin{2cm}
\def\myFootskipMargin{1.5cm}
\usepackage[hmargin={\myHMargin,\myHMargin},
            vmargin={\myVMargin,\dimexpr(\myVMargin - \myFootskipMargin/2)},
            includeheadfoot,
            headsep=0pt,
            footskip=\myFootskipMargin]{geometry}
```

### The style of footer

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Footer
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{lastpage}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength{\headheight}{0cm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}%
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\cfoot{}
\lfoot{{\footnotesize EXAMPLE}}
\rfoot{{\footnotesize  \mbox{}\hfill \thepage /\pageref{LastPage}}}%
```

Comment: your question isn't very clear, why can't you just use the `O` an d`E` options in `fancydr` ?

Comment: As @DavidCarlisle said, with one caveat: It looks like you want an empty footer on even pages and an empty header on odd pages, but the `fancyhdr` package doesn't have any immediate way to set the values of `\headrulewidth` and `\footrulewidth` depending on whether the page number is even or odd. Section 13 (p. 15) in the documentation gives a hint, though: It seems okay to use a conditional inside the definition of these macros … So hang on, let me experiment a little …

Comment: You could/should use the flowfram package for this.  The header/footer can be implemented as a dynamic frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some proof-of-concept example. I did not try to duplicate your exact style, but I trust you may adapt these ideas to your document:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{bophook,fancyhdr,lipsum}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{\ifodd\count0 6pt \else 0pt \fi}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{\ifodd\count0 0pt \else 6pt \fi}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf[ELF]{Even page}
\fancyhf[OLH]{Odd page}
\fancyhf[ERF,ORH]{Page \thepage}
\AtBeginPage{%
  \ifodd\count0 \global\voffset=0mm \else \global\voffset=25mm \fi
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses the flowfram package.

It should be noted that static frames center the contents vertically, while dynamic frames align the tops.

Note: this is about the largest font you can use without `\scalebox`.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,vmargin=.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\newlength{\colwidth}
\setlength{\colwidth}{\dimexpr \textwidth-2\columnsep}
\divide\colwidth by 3

\newstaticframe[1]{\textwidth}{2cm}{0pt}{\dimexpr \textheight-4.5cm}[title]
\begin{staticcontents*}{title}
\centering\Huge This is the title
\end{staticcontents*}

\newflowframe[1]{\colwidth}{\dimexpr \textheight-5cm}{0pt}{0pt}
\newflowframe[1]{\colwidth}{\dimexpr \textheight-5cm}{\dimexpr \colwidth+\columnsep}{0pt}
\newflowframe[1]{\colwidth}{\dimexpr \textheight-5cm}{\dimexpr 2\colwidth+2\columnsep}{0pt}

\newdynamicframe[even]{\textwidth}{2cm}{0pt}{\dimexpr \textheight-2cm}[header]
\begin{dynamiccontents*}{header}
\Huge\hfill\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}
\vfill\hrule height1pt
\end{dynamiccontents*}

\newflowframe[even]{\colwidth}{\dimexpr \textheight-2.5cm}{0pt}{0pt}
\newflowframe[even]{\colwidth}{\dimexpr \textheight-2.5cm}{\dimexpr \colwidth+\columnsep}{0pt}
\newflowframe[even]{\colwidth}{\dimexpr \textheight-2.5cm}{\dimexpr 2\colwidth+2\columnsep}{0pt}

\def\oddlist{3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19}% odd pages >1

\newdynamicframe[\oddlist]{\textwidth}{2cm}{0pt}{0pt}[footer]
\begin{dynamiccontents*}{footer}
\hrule height1pt\vfill
\Huge\hfill\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}
\end{dynamiccontents*}

\newflowframe[\oddlist]{\colwidth}{\dimexpr \textheight-2.5cm}{0pt}{2.5cm}
\newflowframe[\oddlist]{\colwidth}{\dimexpr \textheight-2.5cm}{\dimexpr \colwidth+\columnsep}{2.5cm}
\newflowframe[\oddlist]{\colwidth}{\dimexpr \textheight-2.5cm}{\dimexpr 2\colwidth+2\columnsep}{2.5cm}

\begin{document}
\sloppy% SOP for narrow columns
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

[image: four pages]